# Performing 2 operations asynchronously

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal

I develop an application with Durandal/Breeze/Knockout.

In my javascript, I would like to perform 2 asynchronous operations one after the other.

- The first is collecting all my 'alarms' where transportId is passed by parameter and category is 'Global'
- The second is deleting all these entities collected above

Here is what I do so far:

```
var checkAlarmsOnTransport = function (id) {

    var alarms = ko.observableArray();
    getAlarms(alarms, id, 'Global')
        .then(deleteAlarms(alarms));
};

var getAlarms = function (alarmsObservable, transportId, category, forceRemote) {
    // Input: transportId
    // Input: category
    // Input: forceRemote: boolean to force the fetch from server
    // Output: alarmsObservable: an observable filled with all the alarms

    if (forceRemote)
        queryCacheAlarms = {};

    var p1 = new Predicate('transportId', '==', transportId);
    var p2 = new Predicate('category', '==', category);
    var query = entityQuery.from('Alarms')
                           .orderBy('id')
                           .where(p1.and(p2));

    var isInCache = (queryCacheAlarms === true);

    if (isInCache && !forceRemote) {
        query = query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);
    } else {
        queryCacheAlarms = true;
        query = query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer);
    }

    //old return manager.executeQuery(query)
    //old    .then(querySucceeded)
    //old    .fail(queryFailed);

    var p = manager.executeQuery(query);
    p.then(querySucceeded);
    p.fail(queryFailed);
    return p;

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        console.log("the get return:" + data.results.length); // <---------- added
        alarmsObservable(data.results);
    }
};

var deleteAlarms = function (alarmsObservable) {
    // Input: alarmsObservable: an observable filled with a list of alarms to delete
    // Output: none
    console.log("deleted:" + alarmsObservable().length); // <------------- added
    for (var i = alarmsObservable().length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        alarmsObservable()[i].entityAspect.setDeleted();
    };
};
```

I successfully tested these 2 functionalities independantly successfully. Now I would like to use it asynchronously and it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks to anyone pointing me to the right direction.

---

UPDATE

I updated my code like CodeThug suggested then I added 2 `console.log` lines in my 2 functions to trace what is done. See above.

The console show this:

- deleted:0
- the get return:6

So it seems that the `deleteAlarms` function is called before the `getAlarms` and so the `deleteAlarms` received an input of 0 elements.

Any idea why the calls are reversed?

Comment: Have you tryed to pass a function to the then? I am so sure that it is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getAlarms` method returns like this:

```
return manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(querySucceeded)
    .fail(queryFailed);
```

and you call `getAlarms` like this:

```
getAlarms(alarms, id, 'Global')
    .then(deleteAlarms(alarms));
```

So you are effectively trying to do this:

```
manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(querySucceeded)
    .fail(queryFailed)
    .then(deleteAlarms(alarms));
```

However, you can't chain a `.then()` after a `.fail()`.  `.then()` and `.fail()` are methods that can be called on a promise.  `.then()` returns a promise, you can chain calls in this way:

```
myPromise.then(...).then(...).then(...)
```

And you can have a `.fail()` after a `.then()`, because `.then()` returns a promise:

```
myPromise.then(...).fail(...);
```

However, `.fail()` returns undefined, and you can't call `.then()` on undefined.  So this won't work

```
// This won't work (this is what you're trying to do)
myPromise.then(...).fail(...).then(...);
```

Try this instead:

```
var p = manager.executeQuery(query);
p.then(querySucceeded);
p.fail(queryFailed);
return p;
```

Then you can leave the call to `getAlarms` just as it is:

```
getAlarms(alarms, id, 'Global')
    .then(deleteAlarms(alarms));
```

Comment: I updated my question to show the result after updating my code. Can you take a look? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I would also recommend what jvrdelafuente said - be sure to pass a function to the then() method, not just calling a function in the then method.   `.then(function(){deleteAlarms(alarms);});`   That, combined with the changes I recommended, should take care of it.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem: I had to pass a function to the `then`. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problen can be be in this section:

```
var alarms = ko.observableArray();
getAlarms(alarms, id, 'Global')
  .then(deleteAlarms(alarms));
```

You have to do that:

```
var alarms = ko.observableArray();
getAlarms(alarms, id, 'Global')
  .then(function(){deleteAlarms(alarms);});
```

Because you need to pass a function to the then.

I hope this will help you.